# How to solve this problem in the image below

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

## I am trying to do my best but I am new on this website so there may be some problems with my formatting, So it's a humble request if you think that you can correct my formate plz do it

[[image: [1]]

I tried to solve this system by Chinese Remainder Theorem

As  here $a_1 =1$, $a_2=4$ and $a_3=6$
and $m_1=3$, $m_2=5$, and $m_3=7$
so by applying the Chinese remainder theorem 
here $m= 3\times 5\times 7$

so $m_1= m/3 = 35$, similarly $m_2=21$ and $m_3=15$ 
now the linear congruences are 
$$35x_1\equiv 1 \pmod 3,\quad     21x_2\equiv 1 \pmod 5,\quad    15x_3\equiv 1\pmod7 $$

So in the book the values of $x_1\equiv  2,\ x_2\equiv 1$ and $x_3\equiv 1$
so my doubt is this how the values of $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ are determined.

Comment: I find it easiest to work such problems in stages.  $x\equiv 6 \pmod 7\implies x=6+7t$.  $6+7t\equiv 4 \pmod 5\implies 2t=-2\pmod 5\implies t\equiv -1\pmod 5$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

$x_1,\ x_2$ and $x_3$ are obtained as follows

- $x_1$ is the inverse of $35\bmod 3$. Now $35\equiv 2$, so its inverse  is $2$ since $2\cdot 2\equiv 1\mod 3$.
- Similarly, $x_2$ is the inverse of $21\bmod 5$. However $21\equiv 1\mod 5$, so it is its own inverse.
- Last, $x_3$ is the inverse of $15\bmod 7$, and again $15\equiv 1\mod 7$.

*Note 1* :

The modular inverses are easy to   calculate here by trial and error. In the general case, with bigger numbers, or for  programming, you have to use  the *extended Euclidean algorithm*, which yields a *Bézout's relation* between two coprime numbers:
$$x_1m_1+x_2m_2=1.$$
Considering this relation mod $m_2$, you get $\;x_1m_1\equiv 1\mod m_2$, so $x_1$ is the inverse of $m_1\bmod m_2$. Similarly for the inverse of $m_2\bmod m_1$.

*Note 2*:

The formula to solve the system of (three) linear congruences
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv \alpha_1\mod m_1\\x\equiv \alpha_2\mod m_2\\x\equiv \alpha_3\mod m_3\end {cases}\qquad(\text{moduli pairwise coprime}),$$
uses a *Bézout's  relation* between $M_1=m_2m_3$, $\;M_2=m_3m_1$, $\;M_3=m_1m_2$:
$$ x_1M_1+x_2M_2+x_3M_3=1, $$
and the solution is 
$$x\equiv \alpha_1x_1M_1+\alpha_2x_2M_2+\alpha_3x_3M_3 \mod m_1m_2m_3. $$
This formula is the exact modular analogue of *Lagrange's interpolation polynomial* (for quadratic polynomials in the present case).

Answer (score 0):

So $x = 1 + 3k= 4 + 5j$. So $3k - 5j \equiv 3 \mod 15$.  $k=1,j=0$ and $x \equiv 4 \mod 15$ is such a solution.

So $x = 4 + 15m = 6 + 7n$.  So $15m-7n = 2$.  By Bezout's lemma we know $15a + 7b = 1$ exist and with less thought than effort $15*1 + 7*(-2) = 1$ so $15(2) -7(4) = 2$ and $x \equiv 4 + 15*2 = 6 + 7*4 = 34 \equiv 7*15$ is also a solution.

So by CRT $x \equiv 34 \mod 105$ is the unique class of solutions.

Comment: Nop: $\;64\neq 6\pmod 7\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, let us see what the CRT proof says:

(1) $\;N:=3\cdot5\cdot7=105\;$

(2) $$t_1:=\frac N3=35\;,\;\;t_2:=\frac N5=21\;,\;\;t_3:=\frac N7=15$$

(3)$$\begin{cases}
w_1:=t_1^{-1}\pmod 3=2^{-1}\pmod 3=2\\{}\\
w_2:=t_2^{-1}\pmod5=1^{-1}\pmod 5=1\\{}\\
w_3:=t_3^{-1}\pmod 7=1^{-1}\pmod7=1\end{cases}$$

and thus **a** solution to your system is given by the integer

$$x:=\sum_{k=1}^3a_kt_kw_k\;,\;\;a_1:=1\,,\,\,a_2:=4\,,\,\,a_3:=6\implies$$

$$x=1\cdot35\cdot2+4\cdot21\cdot1+6\cdot15\cdot1=244$$

and if you want **the unique solution modulo $\;N\;$** , then you just have to take

$$\;\overline x=244\pmod{105}=34\pmod{105}\;$$

Check all the above and, in particular, check [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chinese-remainder-theorem/) a simplified yet very useful proof of the CRT for the integers $\;\Bbb Z\;$ . If you know this you'll be able to do **any** such problem, and not matter how many equations (equivalences) you are given.

Comment: Did you mean for the t's and the y's to be the same thing?

Comment: @stevengregory Of course, thanks. I'll edit to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

- $x\equiv 1 \pmod 3\implies x=1+3k $
- $x\equiv 4 \pmod 5\implies 1+3k\equiv4 \pmod 5\\\implies k\equiv
     1\pmod 5\implies x= 1+3(1+5h)=4+15h$
- $x\equiv 6 \pmod 7\implies 4+15h\equiv 6 \pmod7 \implies 15h \equiv 2
     \pmod 7\\\implies h\equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\\implies x=4+15(2+7r)=34+105r $

thus

$$x\equiv 34 \pmod {105}$$

Comment: @BarryCipra ops thanks, I fix!